# Can you specify the hint for a Component from the pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, plexus

If you define a component in your Mojo (groovy or java using maven-plugin-annotations), eg:

```
@Component
Parser parser;
```

And you have multiple implementations of `Parser`, that have

```
@Component(role=Parser.class, hint="simple")
public class SimpleParser implements Parser
```

and

```
@Component(role=Parser.class, hint="complex")
public class ComplexParser implements Parser
```

Is there a way to *choose* the implementation from the pom.xml (or setting.xml or CLI with *-D*)?

I would think it would/should be possible to specify

```
<configuration>
  <parser>complex</parser>
</configuration>
```

but that doesn't work.

(Of course, there is also no way to set an *alias* on a *Component* which is annoying also (or at least would be if you *could* specify the hint), since we use *m_* prefixes on our member variables (ie, in our code, it would actually be `m_parser`.)